# Create gallery doesn't show uploaded images

Tags: media-library

When you do Add Object in a page, for example, a screen is shown where you can see your uploaded images.
But it doesn't work for me. No images are shown. What can it be due to?
If I open the Multimedia Library the images are there.

If I try to upload an image from this interface (add object) I get an error: There has been an error while uploading. Try again later (not literal, translated from spanish).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found that it is caused from the PHP5.5 version, and it's because of the deprecated function mysql_connect(). I've benn able to solve it by changing the file /wp-includes/wp-db.php (line 1142).

```
$this->dbh = mysql_connect( $this->dbhost, $this->dbuser, $this->dbpassword, $new_link, $client_flags );
```

Change with:

```
$this->dbh = @mysql_connect( $this->dbhost, $this->dbuser, $this->dbpassword, $new_link, $client_flags );
```

This makes the gallery to work properly, waiting for the wp compatibility with PHP5.5.